# $ψ \vDash ⊥$ if and only if $ψ$ is a contradiction - why?

Tags: logic, proof-explanation

> $ψ \vDash ⊥$ iff $ψ$ is a contradiction

I am confused as to why this is; the definition of $ψ \vDash \phi$ as I understand is, for all truth assignments that satisfies $ψ$, they also satisfy $\phi$. But  $⊥$ will always be false - so how can any truth assignment satisfy it? It seems to make no sense to say anything can entail $⊥$.

Intuitively for $\leftarrow$, I get that if $\psi$ is a contradiction then its truth value will always equal that of $⊥$ - but then that's still not quite the same as an entailment.

As for $\to$,as I mentioned above the notion of $ψ \vDash ⊥$ just doesn't make sense to me.

Could anyone please help?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2431003/wondering-why-proof-by-contradiction-works?rq=1 The post in this link may not be fully right for you, but there are other links that can be found in it.

Comment: I understand that there are many proof by contradiction questions around; but they seem to have assumed this theorem to be true, instead of trying to prove it...?

Comment: *Proof by contradiction* is a technique to prove theorems. Could the link below be what you are looking for? $\longrightarrow$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/975470/show-that-gamma-cup-neg-phi-is-satisfiable-if-and-only-if-gamma-not?rq=1

Comment: Thank you for your help; but I don‘t think it‘s quite what I am looking for. I actually feel rather comfortable with solving that question

Comment: Ok. I swear, though, there was another post that I went to which I believe would have been quite good for you, but I cannot find it.

Comment: What definition are you using for "$\psi$ is a contradiction"?

Comment: "so how can any truth assignment satisfy  $\bot$ ?" Exactly: if we have $\psi \vDash \bot$, every truth assignment $v$ that satisfies $\psi$ must also satisfies $\bot$. But it can't. Concluson: **if** we have $\psi \vDash \bot$, necessarily $\psi$ must be always *false* i.e. *unsatisfiable* (like e.g $p \land \lnot p$).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Is this kind of like the equivalent of vacuous truth in conditionals...? The two sound very similar but I have never heard people talk about vacuous truth in entailment

Comment: @DerekElkins The definition of contradiction as per the textbook I am using is that it is false under every truth assignment, would a different def. make any difference?

Comment: Not exactly: [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) may  refers to a conditional statement with a false antecedent. Thus, it is linked to: $\bot \vDash \psi$, for every $\psi$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am confused as to why this is; the definition of $ψ⊨ϕ$ as I understand is, for all truth assignments that satisfies $ψ$, they also satisfy $ϕ$. But $⊥$ will always be false - so how can any truth assignment satisfy it?

Exactly.   That is *point* of the argument.

- Since $\bot$ can never be satisfied, therefore there must *never* be assignments which will satisfy $\psi$ *if* we can truly say "every assignment which satisfies $\psi$ also satisfies $\bot$".

  That is: $\psi$ is a contradiction *if* $\psi\vDash\bot$.
- Since "$\psi$ is a contradiction" means $\psi$ can never be satisfied, therefore we can truly say "every assignment which satisfies $\psi$ also satisfies $\bot$" *if* $\psi$ is a contradiction.

  That is: $\psi\vDash\bot$ *if* $\psi$ is a contradiction.
- Thus it is "if and only if" .

Comment: Thank you! But the way you put it make it sounds like a vacuous truth...I don't suppose they are 'related'...? I mean, both are just as counter-intuitive in the same sense

Comment: Yes, they are somewhat related.  Basically, $\psi\models \bot$ means the set of assignments which satisfy $\psi$ must be a subset of the set of assignments which satisfies $\bot$, which is an empty set.