# A counter example for $\Gamma\vDash_{v}B\Longleftrightarrow\Gamma\cup\{\neg B\}$ isn't satisfiable by a model

Tags: logic, examples-counterexamples, first-order-logic, model-theory, satisfiability

I'm trying to disprove:
$\Gamma\vDash_{v}B\Longleftrightarrow\Gamma\cup\{\neg B\}$ isn't satisfiable by a model  (for every assignment).
**In first order logic**.

where $\vDash_{v}$
means that for every assignments  in the model (M) the Logical derivation is correct.

This is contrary to :
[Show that $\Gamma \cup \{\neg \phi\}$ is satisfiable if and only if $\Gamma\not \models \phi$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/975470/show-that-gamma-cup-neg-phi-is-satisfiable-if-and-only-if-gamma-not)
where the the Logical derivation includes the assignment itself (usually marked by $\vDash_{t}$)

Comment: "where $\vDash_v$ means that for every assignments in the model (M) the Logical derivation is correct"? Usually "logical derivation" is $\vdash$.

Comment: I am not talking about proving, but of model semantics.

Comment: So, what's the difference with the [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/975470/288417) you linked?

Comment: There is a difference between if a model (with any assignment, satisfies a proposition) and if only a model with a specific assignment satisfies a proposition.

Comment: Are you in propositional logic, or first-order logic? If you're in propositional logic, I don't understand what you're saying in your last comment. In propositional logic, what's the difference between a model and an assignment?

Comment: First order logic

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA how it's called in English?

Comment: To say that $\Gamma \cup \{ \lnot B \}$ is unsat in model $\mathcal M$ means that $\mathcal M \vDash \Gamma, B$, i.e. in $\mathcal M$ all formulas in $\Gamma$ as well as $B$ are true.

Comment: Thus, what does it mean to find a $v$ such that $\mathcal M,v \vDash \Gamma$ but $\mathcal M,v \nvDash B$? It means that for a specific assignment $v$ to the free variables (if any) that satisfies (in $\mathcal M$) all formulas in $\Gamma$ we have that $B [v]$ does not hold.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA actually as mentioned earlier, your claim will be true only if you add the assignment itself.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA do you have a counter example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "trick" is in the use of universal quantifier (in the meta-): every model $\mathcal M$, every assignment $v$.

"$Γ \cup \{ ¬ B \}$  isn't satisfiable by a model (for every assignment)" means that, for a specific model $\mathcal M$ we have that $\mathcal M,v \nvDash \Gamma, B$ for every $v$, where "$\Gamma \vDash_v B$" means that: for every $\mathcal M,v$, if $\mathcal M,v \vDash \Gamma$, then $\mathcal M,v \vDash B$.

We can imagine the following example: let $\mathcal M$ a model of the usual Euclidean space, let $\Gamma$ the set of geometric axioms **without** the parallel postulate and let $B$ the parallel postulate: we have that $\Gamma \cup \{ \lnot B \}$ is unsatisfiable in $\mathcal M$.

But $\Gamma \nvDash B$, because we know that the parallel postulate in independent from the other Euclid's axioms.

---

A sort of "toy model" $\mathcal M$ where the RHS holds is a model with a single-element domain: $D = \{ a \}$ and an axiom-set $\Gamma = \{ \forall x (x=a \lor x=b) \}$.

We clearly have that $\{ \forall x (x=a \lor x=b) \} \cup \{ \lnot (x=a) \}$ is *unsatsfiable* in $\mathcal M$.

But $\forall x (x=a \lor x=b) \nvDash (x=a)$ because we may consider another model $\mathcal M_1$ with domain $D_1 = \{ a , b \}$ where $(x=a)$ is not satisfied by every assignment.

Comment: Can you give something less rich as Euclidean space? Like a formal model?